# How to create Facebook Pixel to track 3rd party iFrame events on my web page?

Tags: facebook, iframe, pixel, facebook-ads

I have web page where I am using 3rd party form as iFrame.
I would like to use custom audience in Facebook ads to track users who already submited form on my web page.
Facebook's Event Setup Tool don't see and can't locate Submit button in the form (iFrame).
Can you please help how I can track users who already submitted form?

Comment: JavaScript from your page can not interact with the content of iframes loaded from a different origin. The tracking would need to happen from _within_ those 3rd-party frames directly.